# How to set the zoom level for a workbook in OpenPyXL?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I searched around for quite a bit but I'm unable to figure out how to set the default zoom level of a document created using OpenPyXL. Can it be done? If yes, how?

I'm using OpenPyXL 2.0.5.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm using openpyxl version: 2.3.2

and this works for me:

```
for ws in workbook.worksheets:
    ws.sheet_view.zoomScale = 85
workbook.save(excelFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this at the moment. See https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/262/set-the-zoom-of-a-sheet f